# vmc target error ETIMEDOUT behind firewall

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

Config:
Windows 7 64 bits
Ruby19.3 
vmc 0.4.7

From a Admin Command Prompt, I've issued

```
$ set http_proxy=http://j.bosman:XXXXXX@10.1.1.2:8080
$ set https_proxy=https://j.bosman:XXXXXX@10.1.1.2:8080
$ vmc target https://api.cloudfoundry.com -t
```

This is what I get:

> Setting target to https://api.cloudfoundry.com... FAILED
>   Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not      properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2)
>   For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

And the content of the crash file:

> Time of crash:
>     2013-01-09 10:24:53 +0000
>
> Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2)
>
> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in`open'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in`timeout'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in`connect'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in`start'
>   cfoundry-0.4.18/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:124:in `request_uri'
>   cfoundry-0.4.18/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:45:in`request'
>   cfoundry-0.4.18/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:41:in `request_path'
>   cfoundry-0.4.18/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:190:in`request_with_options'
>   cfoundry-0.4.18/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:194:in `get'
>   cfoundry-0.4.18/lib/cfoundry/client.rb:44:in`info'
>   cfoundry-0.4.18/lib/cfoundry/client.rb:35:in `new'
>   vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:354:in`client'
>   vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/start/target.rb:53:in `block in target'
>   interact-0.5.1/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in`with_progress'
>   vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/start/target.rb:52:in `target'
>   mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in`run'
>   mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `block in invoke'
>   mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in`instance_exec'
>   mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'
>   mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in`execute'
>   vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
>   mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership.rb:45:in`start'
>   vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:11:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby193/bin/vmc:23:in`load'
>   C:/Ruby193/bin/vmc:23:in `'

Could you possibly help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried http? Could you share the results of curl http://api.cloudfoundry.com/info ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest vmc should require no proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Jerome, I was just preparing to report this same problem.  In addition, as per a knowledge base article, I set the proxy values at the system environment level (windows xp).  No luck.  Also, as some have suggested, I set the proxy to http://proxy.vmware.com:3128.  Again, no luck.  Hope this is a temporary, not fatal, problem with cloud foundry.

Comment: eightyoctane, I installed curl on my windows machine and executed against www.example.com and api.cloudfound.com/info.  With http_proxy environment variables set, got html output with error msg, "<STRONG>Cache Access Denied.</STRONG></UL></P>
<P>Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request:
<PRE>    http://www.example.com</PRE>
from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.
</P>"

Comment: I see that the error was generated by our proxy server.  The problem is probably local and the error msg did not originate with cloud foundry.

Comment: Jerome, I have a solution that works for me.  First, there seems to be a problem with vmc 0.4.7.  I rolled back to vmc 0.3.21.  Also, I switched to a proxy server that employs a .pac configuration file.  As a consequence, I did not have to set proxy credentials.